# how to decrease size of res bundle android

Tags: android, android-drawable

I  have an application in which i need to use some large model pictures. I put these images in drawable folder corresponding to the densities i.e. drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi etc and these images are increasing size of my apk. What is the best way to use these drawable so that i can downsize my apk. Should i use single set of such images like i put drawable-xhdpi images in drawable folder and delete other images so that every phone will access these pics from drawable folder or is there any other way?

Please suggest me a better way so that i can downsize my apk size without compromising with quality of image.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can do for reducing apk size

1) If it possible try to move images to the web and sync them into your app.

2) If you use image repetition than you can be able to use 9-patch for it.

3) If you compress the `.jpg` files as much as possible, this should greatly reduce the size of your `.apk` file for that you can use many tool for compress Image like  [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

As we know that Apk size is depending upon below two file

**1.) java folder**

**2.) res folder**

But java folder is contain a text file so it is not responsible for the increase the Apk size.

Second one is the res folder in that res folder contain 4 copi of image in your drawable. so to reduce the res folder we have do several thing which is below.

**1.)** **move images to the web** and `async` them into your app.

**2.)**  Make sure your files are completely compressed as much as possible. Use [pngquant](https://pngquant.org/) or [tinypng](https://tinypng.com/) to reduce the image size.

**3.)** Make Sure that Check for any repetition in the images. You might be able to use **9-patch** for it.

**4.)** **make your own drawables** for certain image.

**5.)**  Allow users to **move data to an SD card**.